# How to correctly implement a function that will generate pseudo-random integers with C++20

Tags: c++, random, c++20

I want to note that in C++ the generation of pseudo random numbers is overcomplicated. If you remember about old languages like Pascal, then they had the function `Random(n)`, where `n` is integer and the generation range is from `0` to `n-1`. Now, going back to modern C++, I want to get a similar interface, but with a function `random_int(a,b)`, which generates numbers in the `[a,b]`.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <random>
namespace utils
{
namespace implementation_details
{
    struct eng_wrap {
        std::mt19937 engine;
        eng_wrap()
        {
            std::random_device device;
            engine.seed(device());
        }
        std::mt19937& operator()()
        {
            return engine;
        }
    };
    eng_wrap rnd_eng;
}

template <typename int_t, int_t a, int_t b> int_t random_int()
{
    static_assert(a <= b);
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int_t> distr(a, b);
    return distr(implementation_details::rnd_eng());
}
}
```

You can see that the `distr` is marked with the `static` keyword. Due to this, repeated calls with the same arguments will not cause the construction of the type `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

In some cases, at the compilation time we do not know the generation boundaries.
Therefore, we have to rewrite this function:

```
template <typename int_t> int_t random_int2(int_t a, int_t b)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int_t> distr(a, b);
    return distr(implementation_details::rnd_eng());
}
```

Next, suppose the second version of this function is called more times:

```
int a, b;
std::cin>>a>>b;

for (int i=1;i!=1000000;++i)
    std::cout<<utils::random_int2(a,b)<<' ';
```

**Question**

1. What is the cost of creating `std::uniform_int_distribution` in each
   iteration of the loop?
2. Can you suggest a more optimized function that returns a pseudo-random number in the passed range for a normal desktop application?

Comment: Take a look at the implementation of this class template or use some performance profiler.

Comment: You could do: `template <typename int_t> auto make_random_int3(int_t a, int_t b) { return [d=std::uniform_int_distribution<int_t>(a, b)]() mutable -> int_t { return d(implementation_details::rnd_eng()); }; }`

Comment: Re: "overcomplicated" -- C and C++ give you **tools**, not solutions. Solutions only work in situations they were designed for; if you're outside that space, they don't help. Tools let you build what you need when you need it.

Comment: Well, you started with the premise that the design of C++ random generators is "overcomplicated", then worked your way to a case where having a distribution separate from the generator actually makes sense, and your solution combining the two is inferior. So I suppose the "overcomplicated" design is this way for a reason after all; its authors must have learned a lesson or two since the time of the old languages like Pascal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, for most simple programs such as games, graphics, and Monte Carlo simulations, the API you actually *want* is

```
static xoshiro256ss g;

// Generate a random number between 0 and n-1.
// For example, randint0(2) flips a coin; randint0(6) rolls a die.
int randint0(int n) {
    return g() % n;
}

// This version is useful for games like NetHack, where you often
// want to express an ad-hoc percentage chance of something happening.
bool pct(int n) {
    return randint0(100) < n;
}
```

(or substitute `std::mt19937` for [`xoshiro256ss`](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/Xoshiro256ss/blob/main/xoshiro256ss.h) but be aware you're trading away performance in exchange for... something. :))

The `% n` above is mathematically dubious, when `n` is astronomically large (e.g. if you're rolling a 12297829382473034410-sided die, you'll find that values between 0 and 6148914691236517205 come up twice as often as they should). So you may prefer to use C++11's `uniform_int_distribution`:

```
int randint0(int n) {
    return std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, n-1)(g);
}
```

However, again be aware you're gaining mathematical perfection at the cost of raw speed. `uniform_int_distribution` is more for when you don't already trust your random number engine to be sane (e.g. if the engine's output range might be 0 to 255 but you want to generate numbers from 1 to 1000), or when you're writing template code to work with any arbitrary integer distribution (e.g. `binomial_distribution`, `geometric_distribution`) and need a uniform distribution object of that same general "shape" to plug into your template.

The answer to your question #1 is "The cost is free." You will *not* gain anything by stashing the result of `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, n-1)` into a static variable. A distribution object is very small, trivially copyable, and basically free to construct. In fact, the cost of constructing the `uniform_int_distribution` in this case is orders of magnitude *cheaper* than the cost of thread-safe static initialization.

(There are special cases such as `std::normal_distribution` where not-stashing the distribution object between calls can result in your doing twice as much work as needed; but `uniform_int_distribution` is not one of those cases.)

Comment: I suppose returning a  number in the range [a,b] ( the OP's question) is as simple as adding `a` to the result of your function after calling it with `b-a`?

Comment: @Quuxplusone Thanks. The xoshiro256ss implementation looks simple and fast. It might be better if the u64 were defined as uint_fast64_t or uint_least64_t ?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Yup. If that's something you do a lot, you might add helpers such as `int randint(int a, int b) { return a+randint0(b-a); }` and `int randint_inclusive(int a, int b) { return randint(a, b+1); }`. (Again, beware of corner cases when `b` is astronomically large.)

Comment: @PavelDev: `%rax` doesn't care about flattery — call it "fast" or "least" or whatever, but it's still the exact same 64-bit integer register. Even at the C++ level, you'll find that `std::is_same_v<uint_fast64_t, uint64_t>` and `std::is_same_v<uint64_t, unsigned long long>` — even in C++, they're all typedefs for the same 64-bit type. (Conclusion: There's no point dragging in a header file like `<cstdint>` just so you can use the most flattering names. Computer don't care.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: However, you can avoid static checking(line 8) and request the 64-bit unsigned integer type from the standard library provider. But I admit the existence of a special ideology, which is based on the absence of the use of header files.

Comment: @PavelDev: Yep. :) But it's not _just_ the desire to be single-header-able. The static-assert on line 8 is the computer saying, "If `unsigned long long` isn't the 64-bit type, then something really crazy is happening and I need to stop and get a human's attention." This is the right attitude, IMO. The `uint{,_fast,_least}64_t` approach says, "If `unsigned long long` isn't the 64-bit type, please trust the system anyway and plow ahead using whatever it throws at you." That codepath is astronomically unlikely to be hit, but _if it is hit_, then IMO that's the wrong attitude for the code to have.

Comment: @Quuxplusone. OK, I agree with you. Next questions: 1)Under what license can I use this  xoshiro256ss implementation? 2)Consider using the noexcept specifier

Comment: @PavelDev: (1) README says "Public domain" (as does the header comment in Vigna's C code). (2) `noexcept` is useful on move-constructors to avoid the vector pessimization, but that's all. The inliner can already see that this code doesn't throw.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same `a` and `b` repeatedly, use a **class** with a member function—that’s what they’re for.  If you don’t want to expose your `rnd_eng` (choosing instead to preclude useful **multithreaded** clients), write the class to use it:

```
template<class T>
struct random_int {
  random_int(T a,T b) : d(a,b) {}
  T operator()() const {return d(implementation_details::rnd_eng());}
private:
  std::uniform_int_distribution<T> d;
};
```

Comment: That sounds like `std::uniform_int_distribution<T>` with extra steps. ;)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: It has the desired signature that lacks an explicit URBG.  Of course improving the function-only interface causes it to somewhat more closely resemble the standard library’s!